# Passing CSS Values Through JavaScript to Partial View

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with an MVC Entity Framework Webapp. I have a view that displays other partial views that are updated every 30 seconds. The issue is the dynamic progress bar I am using does not fill up at all and I have tried everything I know. The problem I think is the css that gets passed to the partial view ("width", current_progress + "%"). Here is a pic and the bar is supposed to be over half full...

[image]

Controller methods:

```
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        ViewBag.SumofDon = db.tblDonors.Sum(s => s.DonationAmount);
        return View(db.tblDonors.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Progress()
    {
        return PartialView("_Progress", db.tblDonors.ToList());
    }
```

Dashboard.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<bssp.Models.tblDonor>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
}

@section Scripts{

<script>
function loadProgressPV() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Progress")",
    type: 'GET', // <-- make a async request by GET
    dataType: 'html', // <-- to expect an html response
    success: function(result) {
                $('#progress').html(result);
             }
   });
}

$(function() {
    loadProgressPV(); // first time
    // re-call the functions each 10 seconds
    window.setInterval("loadProgressPV()", 10000);
});
</script>

<script>
$(function () {
    var SumofDon = @ViewBag.SumofDon;
    var current_progress = (SumofDon / 20000) * 100; // 20000 is the goal that can be changed
    $("#dynamic")
        .css("width", current_progress + "%") //This causes the problem?
});
</script>

}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="progress">
        @Html.Partial("_Progress")
    </div>
</div>
```

Partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<bssp.Models.tblDonor>

<div class="row">
<br /><br /><br />
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="well bs-component">
        <h4>@String.Format("{0:C}", @ViewBag.SumofDon) out of $20,000<br /></h4>
        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="progress-bar" id="dynamic" style="width: 0%"></div> @*The width is what gets updated because it found the id of dynamic*@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be awesome and thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work. Are you sure current_progress is properly set?

Comment: @Alex did you try to use $(document).ready(function(){ // your code })

Comment: Your partial has `style="width: 0%"` and your ajax doesn't rerun the jQuery that sets the width.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil I thought so... I tried to set it in the partial view and it does the same thing. I have it placed in the main view because I believe the partial views inherit the js? The bar flash fills to the right place but then goes away if that makes sense.

Comment: Since you are creating the partial and just plopping the html from that onto the page, I would do the width calculation directly in the razor.

Comment: @Alex you should add «()» at the of $(function () { ... })();

Comment: Can you show us the style defined in «.progress-bar»?

Comment: @nurdyguy Duh! That worked perfectly. Just moved the the var's I declared in the script into @{} int he partial view and then replace the 0 in the width element with current_progress. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you pull in the html from the partial with a `style="width: 0%"` but then jQuery that adjusts the css, `$("#dynamic").css("width", current_progress + "%")`, is only run on page load, not after the partial reloads.  You have two options to fix this,

1. Run the jQuery function after the razor loads in from the partial, in the `success` method of the ajax.
2. Since you are using razor to create the partial, why not just do the calculation right there?  That way the partial comes in already set up with the width set.  This is the easier and faster option of the two.